# Can we use terminal to test the modified kernel code?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, system-calls

I am working on linux on ubuntu. I am modifying the source code of linux 2.6.25 by adding a system call while my operating system has some other version of linux installed. To test my modified code, do I need to install an emulator or can I test it on the terminal window itself?
If I can build and compile my linux 2.6.25 on the terminal, how should I do it?

Comment: I would recommend use qemu

Answer (score 2):

You can test your modified kernel by installing that kernel in your current Ubuntu system.

Please follow following steps to install kernel in your system.

1) compile your modified linux kernel

```
  make
```

2) Install that kernel using following command

```
 make modules_install install
```

3) update initramfs as per the changes made in kernel using following command

```
update-initramfs -u -k 3.0.0
```

4)  Finally, Update the grub loader to add the entry of your kernel in boot loader using following command.

```
update-grub
```

5)   Reboot the system and execute the uname -r command to verify that you have updated your kernel or not.

```
reboot

uname -r
```

You can find your updated kernel with your existing kernel on next reboot and check your updated kernel which you have modified with that kernel.

Please let me know if you need any more information,

Answer (score 0):

You can use User Mode Linux.
Using UML, you can even use gdb to debug it.

http://user-mode-linux.sourceforge.net/

http://user-mode-linux.sourceforge.net/hacking.html

Although the document is rather old, it still works in recent kernel.